# SK hynix memory module PC3-10600S-9-11-F3: What does "11-F3" mean?

Tags: memory, ddr3

I know what are:

- PC3 (same as DDR3),
- 10600 (bandwidth in MB/s),
- S (stands for SODIMM, it's RAM for laptops),
- 9 (CAS latency).

Hynix HMT351S6CFR8C-H9 4Gb (front view):

[image]

But I couldn't find anything about what 11 number and F3 mean.
Could anybody help in understanding what it is?

Comment: [This site](http://www.gskill.com/en/faq/DRAM_Memory) lists F3 as being DDR3 RAM (Which is identified as PC3 also). Not sure there's any industry-standard naming convention on these parts.

Comment: @Jonno SK Hynix have their over labelling convention - see my answer.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

#### What does "11-F3" mean

According to [SK Hynix Product Document Label Info. DDR3](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112024609/https://www.skhynix.com/eng/support/technicalSupport.jsp#tg02):

- `11` is the [SPD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_presence_detect#DDR3_SDRAM) Revision -   [JEDEC](https://www.jedec.org/about-jedec) SPD Revision Encoding and Additions level
  (8)
- `F3` is the [Gerber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerber_format) Revision - [JEDEC](https://www.jedec.org/about-jedec) Reference design file used for this design

---

#### [JEDEC](https://www.jedec.org/about-jedec) is a standards body for the Microelectronics Industry

> JEDEC is the global leader in developing open standards for the microelectronics industry, with more than 3,000 volunteers representing nearly 300 member companies.
>
> JEDEC brings manufacturers and suppliers together to participate in more than 50 committees and subcommittees, with the mission to create standards to meet the diverse technical and developmental needs of the industry.

---

#### SPD is an acronym for [Serial presence detect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_presence_detect#DDR3_SDRAM)

> Serial presence detect (SPD) is a standardized way to automatically access information about a memory module. Earlier 72-pin SIMMs included five pins that provided five bits of parallel presence detect (PPD) data, but the 168-pin DIMM standard changed to a serial presence detect to encode much more information.
>
> When an ordinary modern computer is turned on, it starts by doing a power-on self-test (POST). Since about the mid-1990s, this process includes automatically configuring the hardware currently present. SPD is a memory hardware feature that makes it possible for the computer to know what memory is present, and what timings to use to access the memory.

---

#### Gerber refers to the [Gerber format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerber_format)

> The Gerber format is an open 2D binary vector image file format. It is the de facto standard used by printed circuit board (PCB) industry software to describe the printed circuit board images: copper layers, solder mask, legend, etc.

---

#### SK Hynix Product Document Label Info. DDR3

[image]

[image]

Source: [SK Hynix Product Document Label Info. DDR3](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112024609/https://www.skhynix.com/eng/support/technicalSupport.jsp#tg02) <sup>(archive link)</sup>

See Also: [Technical Support < SUPPORT < SK hynix](https://www.skhynix.com/eng/support/technicalSupport.jsp#) for DDR4 and DDR5 Label Info

Comment: The brilliant answer, thanks! I spent quite a time looking into what these F1-F2-F3 mean...

Comment: To decode the part number **(13)**, go to the [archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112024609/https://www.skhynix.com/eng/support/technicalSupport.jsp#tg02), expand the dark gray `DDR3 SDRAM` box in the top half of the page, and download the `Module` PDF. There are also PDFs to decode DDR2 and DDR part numbers.