# Hynix--Gerber Revision--can two difference "Gerber Revision" compatible to each other

Tags: memory

can two difference "Gerber Revision" compatible to each other?

Thank you

4GB 1Rx8 PC3L-12800S-11-13-**B3**

VS

4GB 1Rx8 PC3L-12800S-11-13-**B4**

[SK hynix memory module PC3-10600S-9-11-F3: What does "11-F3" mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/1027557/sk-hynix-memory-module-pc3-10600s-9-11-f3-what-does-11-f3-mean?newreg=e2c94fd27cb3435c9cb3e667814d1ecb)

Gerber Revision JEDEC Reference design file used for this design

Answer (score -1):

will they work  == yes.
together at dual,tripple or quad channel == no.

if you are trying to replace the one with the other 99.9% sure it will work.
but don't add one to the other(will work in most cases but disables some features).

Comment: This answer may or may not be correct but please do try to base your answer on some well sourced material so that the asker can also determine the validity of your answer.