# What is the meaning of 11-B2 in RAM specification (Samsung 2GB 1Rx8 PC3-10600S-9-10-B2)

Tags: laptop, memory, acer-aspire, ddr3

**Please read these details first**
I'm planning to upgrade my Laptop RAM.

This RAM is currently in my Laptop: `Nanya 2GB 1Rx8 PC3 10600S-9-10-B2` 1333 mhz

[image: RAM One Image]

The RAM I'm planning to buy: `Samsung 2GB 1Rx8 PC3 10600S-9-11-B2` 1333 mhz

[image: RAM two Image]

Both RAMs specification almost same except in first RAM case its `10600S-9-10-B2` in second case its `10600S-9-11-B2`.

**Now my question are**

What exactly 10-B2 and 11-B2 means?

Are both RAMs compatible to each other?

here is most close question I have but I didn't understand anything.
[SK hynix memory module PC3-10600S-9-11-F3: What does "11-F3" mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/1027557/sk-hynix-memory-module-pc3-10600s-9-11-f3-what-does-11-f3-mean)

Comment: As per the duplicate's answer.  it's connected the part revision.  Of course, you have two entirely different manufactures.  They are also two entirely different part numbers.